# Cómo validar 4 JButton true para que el 5to JButton dispare una acción

Tags: java

Siguiendo las recomendaciones de alguien de la comunidad, hice un programa con un ActionListener por cada JButton, sin embargo ahora necesito otro ActionListener que verifique **que los 4 botones** anteriores sean **true**, se puede?, los botones son **1)botonvel1 2)botonvel2 3)botondist1 4)botondist2** y el **5)botonsiguiente**, si los 4 anteriores son true haríaa una acción, sino, otra.   Vi por ahí que había una opción llamada isPressed() pero no la recomendaban no entendí porqué.

```
botonvel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonvel1))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel1.getText())<=250 && Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel1.getText())>=180)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad mínima correcta - Esa velocidad puede andar dependiendo de los grados de elevación.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Velocidad mínima incorrecta - Esa velocidad no puede ser mínima.\n");

            Avion error;
            error= new Avion();
            error.sonido_Error();
            }
        }

    }
});

botonvel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonvel2))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel2.getText())<=450 && Integer.parseInt(textfieldvel2.getText())>=350)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad máxima correcta - A esa velocidad probablemente no se dañen los trenes de aterrizaje.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad máxima incorrecta - Probablemente se dañen los trenes de aterrizaje.\n");

            Avion error;
            error= new Avion();
            error.sonido_Error();

            }
        }

    }
});


botondist1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botondist1))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfielddist1.getText())>=2000 && Integer.parseInt(textfielddist1.getText())<=6000)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Distancia mínima correcta - Esa distancia alcanza para que pueda despegar en mínima velocidad.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Distancia máxima incorrecta - Esa distancia no alcanza para despegar a velocidad mínima.\n");

            Avion error;
            error= new Avion();
            error.sonido_Error();
            }
        }

    }
});


botondist2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botondist2))
        { 
            if(Integer.parseInt(textfielddist2.getText())>=2000 && Integer.parseInt(textfielddist2.getText())<=6000)
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Distancia mínima correcta -\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Distancia máxima incorrecta -\n");

            Avion error;
            error= new Avion();
            error.sonido_Error();
            }
        }

    }
});



botonsiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonsiguiente))
        { 
            if(obj.equals(botonvel1)||obj.equals(obj.equals(botonvel2)||obj.equals(botondist1)||obj.equals(botondist2)))
            {
            System.out.println("bien");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.green);
            enunciado.append("\n- Velocidad mínima correcta - Esa velocidad puede andar dependiendo de los grados de elevación.\n");
            }
            else{System.out.println("mal");
            enunciado.setForeground(Color.red);
            enunciado.append("- Velocidad mínima incorrecta - Esa velocidad no puede ser mínima.\n");

            Avion error;
            error= new Avion();
            error.sonido_Error();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es que tu `Jframe`  implemente un `ActionListener`   para todos los controles. No es necesario implementar individualmente un Listener para cada uno.

Comment: bueno por lo visto voy a tener que desistir porque hice un desastre, creo que me perdi e hice cualquiera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mejor es que pongas el grueso de tu código de cada botón en un método aparte y que lo llames con su correspondiente `Listener`. Este método debe devolver un `boolean` que indique si es correcto el resultado o no, ya que quieres saber si es `true`.

Para terminar, en el `Listener` del 5º botón llamas a los 4 métodos y si todos te han devuelto `true` ejecutas el código del 5º:

```
if(metodo1() && metodo2() && metodo3() && metodo4()){
    //Tu código del 5º aquí
}
```

**AMPLIACIÓN**

```
botonvel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        metodo1();

    }
});

botonvel2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        metodo2();

    }
});


private boolean metodo1(){

    Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonvel1)){
        ....
        return true;
        ....
        error.sonido_Error();
        return false;
        }
    }
}

public boolean metodo2(){...}

botonsiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(metodo1() && metodo2()){
        Object obj= e.getSource();
        if(obj.equals(botonsiguiente)) { 
            ....
            error.sonido_Error();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: si, realmente no entiendo porqué no funciona, porque anteriormente a poner los || en el último ActionListener tenía colocados los &&, y sin embargo no funcionaba, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: No funciona porque `obj.equals(botonvel1)||obj.equals(obj.equals(botonvel2)` te tiene que dar falso. Lo que estás preguntando es si el objeto `botonvel1` es igual al objeto `botonvel2`. Lo que yo te digo es que pongas los métodos que llamas dentro de cada botón.

Comment: reemplacé los || por los &&, y ahora funciona, pero siempre me da falso.

Comment: Es que siempre te va a dar falso. Lo que te estoy intentando explicar es que tu sentencia pregunta si dos objetos son iguales, no si lo que esta dentro le dice al usuario "Bien" o "Mal". Eso lo debes hacer con los métodos que llames desde dentro de cada `actionPerformed`

Comment: Ahora entiendo, vos lo que decís es que convierta los métodos de adentro en boolean, pero no deja de ser un JButton si hago éso?

Comment: No, porque al sacalo a un método luego los vas llamando desde dentro de cada `actionPerform` y en el último encadenas todos. Voy a ampliar mi respuesta con más código para que te quede claro.

Comment: Estoy tratando de entenderlo, osea, adentro de los actionperformed de cada JButton le agrego un metodoboolean1(), metodoboolean2(), despuescreo el metodo adentro del action performed y les pongo true o false,

Comment: Los métodos los creas fuera como te puse en el ejemplo, es más, deberías de reutilizar más código haciendo métodos con parámetros que llamas varias veces, por ejemplo todas las salidas que haces con mensajes de "Bien" o "Mal" podrían quedar en uno en el que simplemente pases la frase que añades al enunciado que es lo único que cambia y si respondio bien o mal. Ahorras tiempo, código y si tienes que cambiar algo sólo tienes que cambiarlo en un sitio.

Comment: @Aw3s0meM4n. `obj.equals(botonvel1)||obj.equals(obj.equals(botonvel2)` no compara `botonvel1` con el `botonvel2` Compara si el botón que se dio click el cual está en la variable de tipo Object `obj` fue `botonvel1` o `botonvel2`.

Comment: @Dev. Joel Cierto fallo mío, pero debería funcionarle como le dije.

Comment: @Aw3s0meM4n realmente te entiendo, es más entendí que es un fallo tonto el mío, porque claramente dos botones no son iguales, por eso hay que convertirlos a boolean, lo que estoy viendo es si hay alguna forma más simple con el código que tengo hecho convertirlos en boolean, no sé con un... cast. y si no me queda otra hago de vuelta el que me mandaste vos.

Comment: Y digo hago de vuelta, porque como soy principiante metí codigo en cualquier lado..   :(

Comment: Simplemente copia el código que tienes en cada `actionPerform` y en la parte que dices "Bien" terminas ese bloque `if` con `return true`, y la parte que dices "Mal" termina el bloque `else` con un `return false;`

Comment: me propuse a que si soluciono esto, va a ser lo ñultimo antes que lo convierta en ejecutable, me está dando muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Hola @Awes0mem4n te jode si lo hago y te lo envió mañana para que veas si está bien? No pude responder antes por estar en el trabajo.

Comment: @berlot83 Haz hasta donde puedas y si no te sale abrimos un chat y lo vemos

Comment: Gracias @Awes0mem4n, hoy pude sentarme con tiempo, y salió, exactamente como recomendaste vos. abrazos.

Comment: @berlot83 Un placer amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, no soy 100% nativo Java pero sí con el SDK de Android.

La forma es hacer un sólo listener para los 5 botones, y el método detecta cada botón por medio de un switch - case. Lo malo es que la clase debe implementar ActionListener, para que luego tu IDE te aconseje crear el método Override de actionPerformed, cada uno de los botones llamará ese mismo único método a través de su parámetro puedes saber cual botón fue el que se presionó de modo que fuera del switch-case que tengas puedes validar los 5 botones al mismo tiempo.

Esta forma de hacerlo te permitirá ahorrar lineas de código.

Este código no es exacto porque desconozco la librearia que usas a profundidad pero te queda algo así:

```html
public MiClase implements ActionListener {

 MiClase() {
   botonvel1.addActionListener(this);
   botonvel2.addActionListener(this);
   botonvel3.addActionListener(this);
   botonvel4.addActionListener(this);
   botonvel5.addActionListener(this);

 }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(e) {
        //Para acción en cada botón
        switch (v.getId()){
            case 'botonvel1' :
                this.finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La forma correcta para obtener el control que lanzó el evento. Es mediante  `e.getSource();`